# Is it Possible upgrade Magento 2 from 2.2.6 to 2.4?

Tags: magento2.3

Is it possible updating our system which is now on 2.2.6 straight to version 2.4? Or is it advised / needed to upgrade in steps? Any recommended recent howto on this subject?

Answer (score 3):

You need to first upgrade to Magento 2.3.5 and then upgrade to Magento 2.4.0

Answer (score 2):

It's depends on your website. If it contain more customized code like custom module for payment, shipping and checkout then you might have to go like first upgrade to Magento 2.3.5 and then 2.4 .

But as per my experience Magento 2.4 is totally new and it **support only with php 7.4** so you might have to change your custom code. so why not you directly upgrade to Magento 2.4.0.